# Capistrano + Git - "unable to find" [commit SHA]

Tags: git, github, ssh, capistrano

I'm having difficulty setting up a workstation to use Capistrano to deploy a project. It's a project that I worked on previously, in-house for a client. We used Capistrano + Git on this PHP project without difficulty.

Now I am trying to revisit the project and am setting up a workstation to be able to access the code through github and deploy it to the client server via Capistrano.

I am having no difficulty connecting to github on either my workstation or the client server. I can execute SSH -vT git@github.com on my workstation and get the expected success result.

Likewise I can shell into the server and execute the command to verify that the server can access github.com.

On the workstation side I can clone, pull and push code without difficulty.

However, when I try to run the capistrano deployment script, the script comes to the point of trying to execute the first fetch (or clone) and craps out with an "unable to find [commit SHA hash]" error.

The deployment script hasn't changed since the last time I deployed from the client office.

Here is the output of the cap deploy:

```
  * 2012-11-14 18:52:34 executing `dev'
  * 2012-11-14 18:52:34 executing `setbranch'
  * 2012-11-14 18:52:34 executing `deploy'
  * 2012-11-14 18:52:34 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2012-11-14 18:52:34 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:XXX123/reponame.git master"
    command finished in 2490ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:XXX123/reponame.git /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha; fi"
    servers: ["server.alias"]
    [server.alias] executing command
 ** [server.alias :: out] error: unable to find 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha
 ** fatal: object 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha not found
    command finished in 1681ms
 *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/releases/20121115025239; true"
    servers: ["server.alias"]
    [server.alias] executing command
    command finished in 293ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:XXX123/reponame.git /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/serverusername/dev.site.com/code/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha; fi'" on server.alias
```

(I've changed some of the names in the output code to project the client.)

I initially encountered this problem while struggling to set things up on a Windows Vista PC. Thinking that Windows was the problem, I then set up an Ubuntu virtual box, got that up and running quickly, and am having the same result.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `git reset -q --hard 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912-github-commit-sha` seems wrong, and looks like it should be `git reset -q --hard 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912`. Can you track down where that string is built?

Comment: What happens if you try to pull from git through Capistrano's shell?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with berkes that your cap recipe may be looking for the wrong SHA, but since you report that it hasn't changed, I'll throw out this possibility since it recently happened to me:

Ensure that the SHA still exists on the branch.

We rewrote some of our history, and the previous SHA's were no longer in the repo. I'd look through `git log` for the SHA. It might be faster to just create a throw-away branch and reset to the SHA `git checkout -b lost_sha` && `git reset --hard 8d28f09e2b85ebac6da912`. Git would complain if the SHA wasn't found.

It's possible that your script didn't change, but the repo did.